# What's the disadvantage of using higher version of Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I can choose from Windows 7 professional, enterprise and ultimate.
Is there any 'cons' of using ultimate version?
(for example, higher version may be slower)

Answer (score 5):

There really arent any disadvantages, only advantages.  However, they might not be useful to you.

Check out this [chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_7_editions#Comparison_chart) on Wikipedia.  It shows the differences between the versions.

Comment: Does install size/disk usage vary?

Comment: Not really.  In reality much of the functionality that is "missing" for a lower version is actually still in the lower edition, in case you ever upgrade, its just disabled.

Comment: Except for the "It costs more" disadvantage.

Answer (score 3):

The only negative difference is in price of legitimate product keys. If you find the excess features of ultimate unwanted, you can disable them in Programs and Features in the Control Panel.